# agora.io doesn't show me function,action,usage for me

Tags: agora.io

in https://www.agora.io/ in project section the function and usage and action parts doesn't appear for me can someone please help me I've tried every thing but it seems the site won't show me fully (I've refreshed the site multiple times)

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only. This doesn't look like one.

Comment: You need to login to your account on http://console.agora.io

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.